# verifying non-additive join decomposition

Tags: database-design, normalization

I am reading a DMBA book and have come across non-additive (lossless) join property. The algorithm for decomposition into multiple tables is borderline useless for practical work, so I am frequently relying on intuition.

I am wondering, how does a typical DB designer tackle decomposition? By that I mean, is there a helper tool that takes a relation schema + functional dependencies as an input and outputs possible lossless-join decompositions?

Comment: Decompositions are just a step towards normalization. Things will be more clear when you will read about normalization.

Comment: So if you follow normalization steps, you automatically also get non-additive join property?

Comment: Yes, both for the algorithms for Boyce-Codd Normal Form, as well as for the algorithm for the Third Normal Form.